# How to Assign random value of an array to another array and unique value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, combinations

I am trying to build a library system for a particular class with book and student and issue book table.

I have two array called `Students` and `Books`

Suppose the elements in students array are `$students=(st1,st2,st3,st4,st5,st6);`
and elements in books are are `$books=(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6);`
I want to distribute books to students in random fashion such that:

- condition 1: All students should get to read all books in 6
  iterations.
- condition 2: No students should  get duplicate books(ie no    books
  should be assign twice.
- Process of Distribution: In every iteration each students get one
  book to read out of 6 and should be unique.
- Note: No of iteration will always either equal to number of books or less than number of books.

  For getting duplicate check I have a table `issued_book` where i am storing value of student ID(foreign key) and book ID(foreign key) assign to them in each iteration in `issued_book` table.
- Every time all students returns books together then assign new one.

But somehow I am not getting unique combinations for each students while assigning book array to student.

Comment: Homework possibly?

Comment: yeah kind of trying to build something

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a "random fashion" ?

If you assign b1 to st1 and so on and so forth:

S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6

---

b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6

b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b1

b3 b4 b5 b6 b1 b2

b4 ........

b5 ........

b6 ........

I.e. each person can past the book he or she has to the person on the left or to the right on each iteration.